# How do I get the actual visible cursor's line number

Tags: qt, user-interface

I can get the line of the cursor by using `QTextEdit.textCursor().blockNumber()`, but when one line wrap into multi-lines, it can not return the actual line number.

How can I do that?

Comment: warped lines are usually treated as one line, all my editors works like that: Notpad++, vi, ... .

Comment: Sure, I use Vim. But I need to popup a window under the "actual" line of the `TextEdit`, so I have to do it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wasn't sure it will work, so I wrote a quick test application (Qt 5.0.1) and this works, here is piece of it:

```
void MainWindow::on_plainTextEdit_cursorPositionChanged()
{
    QPlainTextEdit *edit = qobject_cast<QPlainTextEdit *>(sender());
    Q_ASSERT(edit);
    QTextCursor cursor = edit->textCursor();
    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::StartOfLine);

    int lines = 1;
    while(cursor.positionInBlock()>0) {
        cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Up);
        lines++;
    }
    QTextBlock block = cursor.block().previous();

    while(block.isValid()) {
        lines += block.lineCount();
        block = block.previous();
    }
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(lines));
}
```

Comment: Awesome solution! I just translate it into Python and it's works! I fill-in some `a` into TextEdit to guess the length of text on every line before. It's very nasty.

Comment: The first while loop doesn't work for me b/c it's counting wrapped lines.  Will post another solution below.

Comment: @Wingware yes it counts wrapped lines, as it was requested in question (see comments under question). If you don't want count wrapped lines then just count blocks (code is simpler).

Comment: In my test case there are multiple physical lines but only one block for the whole content.  Also, the block is reporting a lineCount of 1 even though there are 6 physical lines.  I suspect that is because we are using setHtml() to set the text on the QTextEdit and the lines are produced with <br> tags.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar solution in Python.  It fixes the problem I noted in comment on the earlier one above.  This is a method in a subclass of `QTextEdit`:

```python
def getLineAtPosition(self, pos):
  cursor = self.textCursor()
  cursor.setPosition(pos)

  cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.StartOfLine)
  lines = 0

  lines_text = cursor.block().text().splitlines()
  lines_pos = 0
  for line_text in lines_text:
    lines_pos += len(line_text) + 1
    if lines_pos > cursor.position() - cursor.block().position():
      break
    lines += 1

  block = cursor.block().previous()
  while block.isValid():
    lines += block.lineCount()
    block = block.previous()

  return lines
```

Comment: This counts physical lines, not wrapped lines as apparently the OP wanted (sorry, my confusion).  Still maybe useful so leaving it here.  Note that this works if you setHtml() w/ text that has <br> producing lines.  However, apparently there's only one block in that case.

Answer (score -1):

`QTextCursor` has a lot of useful methods, like:

```
int QTextCursor::position () const
```

Returns the absolute position of the cursor within the document. The cursor is positioned between characters.

and

int QTextCursor::positionInBlock () const

Returns the relative position of the cursor within the block. The cursor is positioned between characters.

This is equivalent to `position() - block().position()`.

Comment: `position()` returns the length of the characters. I need a visible line number...